# Apache NiFI ExecuteStreamCommand Wrong Output

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I have NiFi flow that runs some shell scripts using the **ExecuteStreamCommand** processor and the output of the **ExecuteStreamCommand** is not correct.

**The Shell i run is:**

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep kibana | wc -l) > 0 )); then echo "1"; else echo "0"; fi;
```

Is the service is up then **1** if is down then **0**, simple but the output is wrong, not matter is the service is up or down the output is always **1**.

**Here is a demo if the flow:**

https://youtu.be/4e00rzerjSQ

Comment: you don't have real input to your script, so try to use `ExecuteProcess` instead of `ExecuteStreamCommand`

Comment: or set `Ignore STDIN` to `true`

Comment: Hi @daggett i actually do, this is minifi flow that get data from a mysql rdbms based on localhost ip and creates this service check scripts

Comment: Hi Ignore STDIN did the trick - can post this as an answer and give a more detailed info on why would this have this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **original relationship** use **output stream relationship** connect to log attribute processor.

**Flow:-**
[image]

if you connect **original relation** to log attribute that means the contents of **generate flowfile** is passing to **original relationship**.

if you connect output stream i.e **output of your shell script** will be in flowfile content.
[image]
**Output:-**
[image]
**Content:-**

[image]

Comment: i use original connection as i enabled the "Output Destination Attribute" option so i leaves me with only one relation